# How to make an input of type number a controlled component in react

Tags: reactjs

```
export default function Form() {
const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    numOfQs: 0
})
console.log(user)
function handleUserDataChange(event) {
    setUser(prevUser => {
        return {
            ...prevUser,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
    })
}
return (
    <>
        <input 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="username"
        name="name"
        value={user.name}
        onChange={handleUserDataChange} />
        <input 
        type="number" 
        name="numOfQs"
        value={user.numOfQs}
        onChange={handleUserDataChange} />
    </>
)}
```

I was trying to build my form using react, and when I tried to use input[type: number] on the form field it was giving me this error, don't know why. I was reading through [react docs about forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), and everything from the checkbox, radio buttons, textarea was all working fine. but when I used an input element of the type number, I got the following error.

*!Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See ***fb.me/react-event-pooling*** for more information.

so, the problem only arises when an input of type "number" is introduced. when I remove it all of my other form elements work fine.

I'm still in the learning phase of react. please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because the event that passed into the function is used as an asynchronous event.

To fix this, decompose the event object

```
function handleUserDataChange(event) {

    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setUser(prevUser => {
        return {
            ...prevUser,
            [name]: value
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks, Sachila. Now it's working fine. can you suggest me some resources that i could read about. i know what asynchronous means, but an asynchronous event, i can't understand it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing#:~:text=Asynchronous%20programming%20is%20a%20technique,is%20presented%20with%20the%20result.

Comment: I haven't changed the code except the answer you suggested & now, i'm getting this error  when i click on the up or down arrows.  Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type number to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Comment: for input values, create a useState variables and use it for the value. like `value={userName}` Also update the the state variable in the onchange method